# Handling multiple MongoDB databases with Eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have many MongoDB databases, all containing the same collection. I want to expose these data with Eve.

I would like to invoke a GET to `/aaa/bbb/mycoll` and get data from collection `mycoll` in e.g. DB `mydb_aaa_bbb`.

My question is: is this possible and in case how can I do that?

My guess is that I should set the DB name programmatically using *event hooks*, or maybe by exploiting the `mongo_prefix` mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that with Eve 0.6 or higher. Check out [`mongo_prefix` option in configuration](http://python-eve.org/config.html) and [the example how to use it](http://python-eve.org/authentication.html#authdrivendb). Of course, for your use case, you should figure out which database to use from URL in some of the event hooks, just like you mentioned.